# Creating a list with c:foreach and placing an onClick listener with a parameter on the items

Tags: jquery, spring, model, foreach, onclick

I'm trying to build a list of items in a jsp page in the following way:
I have a Spring Mvc controller which returns the results of a search in a model. I am able to access objects in this model via the following code in the jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${poiList}">
            <div class="manageListItem">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getName()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getAddress()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getType()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getRating()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The list gets printed nicely. However, I would like each item to become clickable and redirect to a certain page (more like send another request to the controller) on click.

So far, I have tried jquery, but if I don't build the list there, I cannot access a listItem's ID, which would be needed for the request. It would be nice if I could somehow pass it as a parameter with the onClich property of the manageListItem div, but that does not seem possible.
I could also do the whole thing in jQuery, but this seems cleaner and also, I have no idea on how to access the Model's attributes in jQuery :)

What is the best method to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an onclick listener on the row, and you can reference the item id using JSP EL as normal.  Have a look at this example:

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${poiList}">
  <div class="manageListItem">
    <table>
      <tr onclick="alert('I clicked on '+${listItem.id});">
        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getName()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getAddress()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getType()}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getRating()}"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

You could always call another function, or have jQuery stuff in the onclick part; the main point is that you can use JSP EL to build the javascript code that can react to events.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.manageListItem td', function(e){
    //i think the value is just the text in the TD, no?
    window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '?listItemId=' + $(this).text()
});
```

Using jQuery's `.on()` we can delegate event listening to a static element. For dynamic elements, this will ensure that they can still have events fire. `.on()` accepts 3 arguments: the event, the element we want to fire the event from, and of course, the callback function to run when the event has triggered.

Based on your markup above, I'm assuming that the value you print inside your `td` is your listItemId.

The line `window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '?listItemId=' + $(this).text()`

Will grab the protocol

```
http:
```

Then we concatenate the string with two `//` trailing forward slashes ( if there is no http/https, // before a url is still valid).

Then we grab the host location

```
stackoverflow.com
```

then we append a query string with the text that was inside of the TD.

```
?listItemId=8
```

If for instance, your `c:out` printed 8, then the wh ole url would look like

`http://stackoverflow.com?listItemId=8`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't mentioned what your browser requirements are, but most "modern" browsers will support the use of `data-` attributes.  In your case:

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${poiList}">
            <div class="manageListItem" data-item-id="${listItem.getId()}">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getName()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getAddress()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getType()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getRating()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Now, its a simple matter of using the [jquery data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method:

```
$('div.manageListItem').click(function(evt) {
     var id = $(this).data('itemId');
     alert('Huzzah, you clicked on ' + id);
});
```

FYI, if you create an element with an attribute called `data-my-item-id`, you need to retrieve it using jquery using `myItemId`.  Everything after the initial `data-` is converted into camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all these ideas!

In the end, I found it easiest to write the redirect command right into the tag's onClick attribute:

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${poiList}">
            <div class="manageListItem" onclick="window.location.replace('/poi/display/' + ${listItem.id})">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getName()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getAddress()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getType()}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listItem.getRating()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

This way each of the listitems clicked send a request with their own ID and the controller handles that as expected.